# muliple object is not push into array and not create array of object

Tags: javascript, angular

```
var myArray = ["id", "name", "location", "email", "gender", "tel / fax", "language preference", "credit card type"]

    for (var key in myArray) {
        this.col.data = myArray[key];
        this.col.type = "text";
        console.log('col=>' + JSON.stringify(this.col))
        this.dynamicColumns.push(this.col);
        console.log('dynamicColumns=>' +            
        JSON.stringify(this.dynamicColumns))       
    }

but i want this output:- [{"data":"id","type":"text"},{"data":"name","type":"text"},{"data":"location","type":"text"},......]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
It iterates through an array and returns a new array with the new values.

```js
var myArray = ["id", "name", "location", "email", "gender", "tel / fax", "language preference", "credit card type"]

this.dynamicColumns = myArray.map(ele => {
 return { data: ele, type: 'text' }
})
console.log(this.dynamicColumns )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and create object in desired format for each element.

```js
var myArray = ["id", "name", "location", "email", "gender", "tel / fax", "language preference", "credit card type"]

let op = myArray.map(ele =>({ data: ele, type: 'text' }))

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = ["id", "name", "location", "email", "gender", "tel / fax", "language preference", "credit card type"];

var dynamicColumns = [];

for (var key in myArray) {
  this.col = {};
  this.col.data = myArray[key];
  this.col.type = "text";
  console.log('col=>' + JSON.stringify(this.col))
  dynamicColumns.push(this.col);

}
console.log('dynamicColumns=>' +
  JSON.stringify(dynamicColumns));
```